# How to download file without login to wordpress account?

Tags: links, user-access

The following link is used to share individual customer/user to download invoice PDF file. But each time they have to login and download PDF file. I want this link should download PDF file without login by user. `https://example.com/my-account/orders/?order_id=12345&invoice_type_id=invoice&get_invoice=1&save_pdf_invoice=1`

Comment: This type of PDF isn't coming from WP Core, so you will probably need to contact the support channels of the plugin that generates the PDF.

Comment: Yes it is generated by booster plugin. But in their official document they mentioned that Only logged in users can open PDF documents via link. But I want it to bypass login and download it, Is it possible?

Comment: I found this blog https://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-allow-to-pay-for-order-without-login/  here code will make user to get access and pay for an pending orders without login. Like this is it possible with my link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got solution that this plugin has setting to save pdf file in temp directory and has option to change temp directory. Then I added path to save files and that file is accessed directly to download file. Sorry for creating this post without looking into plugin's setting.